# Where can I find Google Cloud Compute golang sdk for Compute, Service account etc

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform

Looking for golang sdk for Google Cloud Compute. 
There are thousands of links, Which one is the official golang sdk for google cloud platform for compute , network, service account auth etc?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the official docs with install instructions:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/libraries#google_apis_go_client_library